# Detect changing value with jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to detect if a change is happening inside of `.selector`. The content always contains a $ symbol. E.g. `>$0.95<` or `>$1,990.00<`

I have found many answers that involve something like the following, but do not work in this case because of the presence of the $ symbol.

```
$(".selector").change(function(){
     if(parseFloat(this.value) < $99.00){
        /* action */
     }
```

What could I use in this case to get a change in number value?

**EDIT**

The .selector is either a div (with the only content being `$99.00` or other number)

**OR**

an input field which is changed / calculated by another jquery function according to user input in other fields.

Jquery 1.4.4

I am currently struggling with nothing of .live or .change reacting actually.

Comment: Please more detail about the element which represent by ".selector". Is it input? select box or anyorder element?

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there, either there is a typo in your code either you forgot to remove $ from your value ($99.00):

```
$(".selector").change(function(){
     if(parseFloat(this.value) < 99.00){
        /* action */
     }
});
```

Moreover what you could do is remove this first character with something like :
`parseFloat(this.value.substring(1))`

Comment: Typos should be left in comments

Comment: @JordanS this is not clear if it is a typo or not plus there could be an issue with parseFloat if the starting character is not a number.

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can try the below code

```
$(".selector").change(function(){
if(($(this).val())< Number("$99".replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,"")))
{
alert("small value");
}   
else
{    
alert("greater value");
}
})
```